# Add a property into class object within a list

Tags: c#

I have a list with class object. I would like to know how to add a property into it later on, without implementing the property directly into that class from the beginning.

```
public class Example{

   public int ExampleInt {get; set;}
   public string ExampleString {get; set;}
   public double ExampleDouble {get; set;}
}
```

I have a list of `Example` like: `List<Example>`

Now, how can I add, lets say, `ExampleBool` property into every object inside that `List<Example>`, without implementing it directly into `Example` class?

Comment: If downvote, I would like to know the reason to improve my future question.

Comment: Well, reason one: this code won't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# is statically typed language. You cannot dynamically add or remove class members. But you can create new anonymous class which will have any properties you want:

```
var examples = new List<Example>();
var result = from e in examples
             select new {
                 e.ExampleInt,
                 e.ExampleString,
                 e.ExampleDouble,
                 ExampleBoolean = true
             };
```

In some cases it might be helpful to use dynamic object instead of statically typed classes. Take a look on [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - it allows you to dynamically add and remove members at runtime. But you will lose IntelliSense, performance will suffer, and you will have to create each object from scratch:

```
var examples = new List<dynamic>
{
    new ExpandoObject(), // initially it does not have any properties
    new ExpandoObject()
};

for (int i = 0; i < examples.Count; i++)
{
    examples[i].ExampleInt = i;
    // etc
}

for (int i = 0; i < examples.Count; i++) // we add new property
    examples[i].ExampleBoolean = i % 2 == 0;

foreach(var example in examples)
    Console.WriteLine($"{example.ExampleInt} {example.ExampleBoolean}");
```

Comment: I see, thanks! In cases where you got a class with too many properties, is there any way to shorten the declaration ? This following code wont work obviously, but something like "`...select new{ e.Example, ExampleBoolean = true };` ?

Comment: @ipid it will work too - you will have `Example` property with whole `Example` object. But keep in mind - you cannot pass anonymous objects between methods. If you need to do that, then you should create new named class. Also you can use something like AutoMapper which will simplify mappings between different classes

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in a standard way, but you can create inheritor

```
public class ExampleWithBool { public bool ExampleBoolean {get; set;}}
```

Also, anonymous class (see Sergey's answer).